# Crash: this may be due to a corruption of the heap

Tags: c++, qgis, qwt

I'm using qwt5 in my plugin with qgis 2.8.1 ( (version 32 bit) which use qwt6).When I run my C++ program it crashes with this error:

[image]

the problem occurred in this function (running in debug) :

```
//delete all the items attached to QwtPlot
const QwtPlotItemList &list = m_pPlot->itemList ();
qDeleteAll(list.begin(), list.end());
```

I replaced this function with:

```
QwtPlotItemIterator it = list.begin();
while ( it != list.end() )
{
  QwtPlotItem *item = *it;
  ++it; // increment before removing item from the list
  item->attach(NULL);
  delete item;
}
```

but the same crash occurs again in this instruction:

```
delete item;
```

Please, have you an idea about this problem?

Comment: The output window may have more diagnostic information.
    HEAP[qgis-bin.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlFreeHeap( 02D20000, 123B6D10 )
    Windows has triggered a breakpoint in qgis-bin.exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in qgis-bin.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

    This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while qgis-bin.exe has focus.

Answer (score 3):

From [Qwt User's Guide](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_plot_dict.html#a9cbb1c5c22de93594b7e2524af108f55)

> A QwtPlotItemList of all attached plot items.
>
> **Use caution when iterating these lists, as removing/detaching an item will invalidate the iterator**. Instead you can place pointers to objects to be removed in a removal list, and traverse that list later.

**Emphasis mine.**

Comment: thank your for your response , i think that this message (Invalid address specified to RtlFreeHeap( 02D20000, 123B6D10 )) is a general error ,maybe it is related to memory management, and this is the callstack location after the crash : (ntdll.dll!77e70574() ).Can anybody give me a hint what this could be or why the crash happened? Or any suggestio how I can find out the source of that problem?

Answer (score -2):

Move `delete item` outside of loop. Now you delete `item` multiple times.

Comment: That is the point.   He's trying to loop through all the pointers and delete them.